# chokidar: onchange event for a file is possibly triggered to fast

Tags: node.js, file, sublimetext3, onchange, is-empty

We are watching for file changes using chokidar with nodejs on an Ubuntu server. It works pretty fine, but sometimes I think we have a problem with the way a file is saved when changed: in chokidar the "onchange" event is triggered, but when we read the file in the callback, it is empty or (rarely) not written completely. We don’t know if it is a problem caused by the text editor writing the file, the operating system on the client computer, the OS or filesystem (ext4) on the server or if it is some kind of bug in chokidar.

This empty file problem is now happening almost every time by file changes made from one computer (mac, latest osx version) where sublime 3 is used. In sublime we tried the setting “atomic_save” (creates a temp files and then overwrites the original file), but it did not solve our problem:

1. With *atomic_save* set to “false” the file seems to be always empty in the onchange event and
2. With *atomic_save* “true” it is sometimes empty and sometimes partly written.

We had this problem before with phpstorm, but after switching to  *‘use “safe write” (save changes to a temporary file first)’* - so the same setting as atomic_save in sublime, that’s also why we tried atomic_save in sublime -, the onchange event was triggered correctly after the complete was written.

So our question is, is there a way to have the “onchange” triggered when the file is completely written somehow (in chokidar, in an OS, in sublime)? Or do we have to check the file size in the “onchange” event until hasn’t changed for some time (not so nice)? Or does our problem maybe occur because of something else?

We would appreciate any hints! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking through the [performance](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar#performance) section of the `chokidar` README, I found the following:

> `awaitWriteFinish` (default: `false`). By default, the add event will fire when a file first appear on disk, before the entire file has been written. Furthermore, in some cases some `change` events will be emitted while the file is being written. In some cases, especially when watching for large files there will be a need to wait for the write operation to finish before responding to a file creation or modification. Setting `awaitWriteFinish` to `true` (or a truthy value) will poll file size, holding its `add` and `change` events until the size does not change for a configurable amount of time. The appropriate duration setting is heavily dependent on the OS and hardware. For accurate detection this parameter should be relatively high, making file watching much less responsive. *Use with caution*.
>
> - *`options.awaitWriteFinish` can be set to an object in order to adjust timing params:*
>
>   - `awaitWriteFinish.stabilityThreshold` (default: `2000`). Amount of time in milliseconds for a file size to remain constant before emitting its event.
>   - `awaitWriteFinish.pollInterval` (default: `100`). File size polling interval.

This looks like it could solve your problem, assuming that more than a few seconds elapse between file saves.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't saw this setting. Well, I have the latest chokidar installed, but somehow this setting makes no difference. Even with an awaitWriteFinish object and stabilityThreshold set to 10000, let the onchange event trigger instantly (and not after 10s).

But I just tried another setting myself, "usePolling: true" and it works then. Well, this does not seems to be very perfomant, but it least it works.